# How to download file to server dynamically using php

Tags: php, curl, installation

I was curious to know if there was a way to download a file from SERVER A and put it on SERVER B where SERVER A has the ability to dynamically change what's in the downloaded file.

The point behind it is that I'm trying to build an error handler for a tool that will be used when a file that is a needed part of a tool goes missing. It would be like WordPress realizing there is a file missing on your site and your site sends a request to wordpress.com to get the missing files like this:

**(SERVER B):** PHP spits out error on `include`

**(SERVER B):** PHP tries to get a file installer for the missing files from SERVER A by saying SERVER B is missing `FILE A`, `FILE B`, `FILE C`, etc...

for the step above I was thinking it could be done using this:

```
file_put_contents("missing_installer.php", "http://SERVER_A.com/mi_inst_installer.php?query-asking-for-missing-item(s)=missing-item", 'r'));
```

**NOTE (only if you don't understand what the above code does):** The above code is supposed to tell SERVER A's PHP file, mi_inst_installer.php, to spit out data (the installer) and put it into file, missing_installer.php, on SERVER B

**(SERVER B):** PHP installs missing files using the newly obtained missing_installer.php

Any ideas on what to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use cURL for dynamics on SERVER A's Side:

```
function curl($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    $return = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    return $return;
}
file_put_contents('missing_installer.php', curl('http://SERVER_A.com/mi_inst_installer.php?query-asking-for-missing-item(s)=missin-item'));
```

Jacky's answer is good only if `allow_url_fopen` is set to 1.

also use [PHP's reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) for cURL transfer options (lets you customize how the the request is sent and/or returned). Also, it's a good idea to get used to how cURL works generally; see [the other PHP reference (client URL library)](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

Comment: can I have the PHP reference URL?

Answer (score 2):

try something like this:

```
$mycontent = file_get_contents('http://SERVER_A.com/mi_inst_installer.php?query-asking-for-missing-item(s)=missin-item');
file_put_contents('missing_installer.php', $mycontent));
```

you need to get (using `file_get_contents()`) the contents of the downloaded file first and then put it into the second parameter of `file_put_contents()` first.

Comment: Is your last line supposed to mean that you have to use the file_get_contents() first. I'm sorry if it's a stupid question, I just need to be sure I'm implementing it correctly.

Comment: yes, it's right, first you use file_get_contents (for download) and after, file_put_contents (for create a file with the content you downloaded first) it's like a copy ;)